# Fully un- and reinstall Cinnamon (all config data and stuff too)

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, configuration, cinnamon, reset

I have Cinnamon installed on my 14.10 system and recently it stopped working properly. Maybe I did a bad config and therefore want to completely (200%) delete and reset all data belonging to this for having a fresh clean installation later.

The original question about how to solve the issue was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572805/cinnamon-hangs-immediately-after-startup-no-interaction-with-panel-and-popup-no), but nobody answers, so I ask for it a bit different.

I already performed `sudo apt-get purge cinnamon` as well as `gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon`, but after any reinstallation it still suffered from the same error.

Please help me to understand what happened and how to get rid of the bad setting I think is responsible for this.

Comment: Look at your /home/<username>/ folder for any setting of cinnamon and delete them.

Comment: Okay, now i have additionally run `apt-get autoremove` and `autoclear` which deleted some other cinnamon packages. Then I deleted the `~/.cinnamon` and `~/.config/cinnamon-sessions`. I will now reinstall it and check if it works. Thank you so far.

Comment: I did not get happy with this, as after reinstalling it, I still encounter the same error. Can you tell me how to delete the downloaded package-installers, as running apt-get install cinnamon did not download anything but used locally stored data?

Comment: `apt-get clean` should remove installation packages. May be you can look for them in `/tmp`

Comment: Thank you, but I ran `sudo apt-get autoclean` (spellling error in comment above), which obviously it did not delete them. I will try looking in /tmp later as I am currently surfing with another pc.

Comment: No, `autoclean` removes packages that were previously installed but no longer needed, and `clean` removes temporary downloaded files. (`/var/cache/apt/*` folder)

Comment: So is `sudo apt-get clean` enough or do I have to add `cinnamon` or `cinnamon*` as another argument?

Comment: No arguments, just sudo apt-get clean is enough.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @kirill-a: No, still same problem. But only on my current user! If I create another user, that one can log in using Cinnamon as DE.

Comment: It means there's something in your home folder still left.

Comment: Don't know what it should be! Even did a search for "cinnamon" and moved every folder and file into trash.