# Gnome-session broken for specific account, works for other accounts

Tags: gnome, xorg, mutter

Running Ubuntu 12.04, I installed `gnome-shell` (GNOME 3) and used it for some days with no problem.
Yesterday, I broke it following this sequence of events:

- I played with the accessibility menu in the top panel, launching the keyboard onscreen at one point. Suddenly, everything froze.
- I tried to use `xkill` and point the x on this onscreen keyboard, or on the top panel but it did not kill it.
- I opened TTY1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), logged in, and restarted the machine.

Since then, my GNOME Shell is broken. I can log in using Unity, but if I log in using GNOME, I only see the wallpaper and the mouse pointer.

Interesting to note:

- I have reinstalled `gnome-shell` doing `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell` followed by `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` several times, but it doesn't change anything.
- I **can** log in under GNOME Shell perfectly if I use **another account** (be it guest or a newly created one).
- I tried to follow the steps in [The Definitive Guide to Getting Your Linux Desktop Back](https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop-recovery/the-definitive-guide-to-getting-your-linux-desktop-back/) until the step "Try to reinstall the window manager".
  I understand that the window manager associated to Gnome is mutter. I tried to purge it (in order to reinstall it), but the terminal says `Package mutter is not installed, so not removed`. However, if I do `man mutter`, I can read the manual. Furthermore, I can run `gnome-shell` on the guest session and I checked that it uses mutter by using `wmctrl -m`. So I don't understand how should I proceed to purge and reinstall it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Having same problem with Cinnamon. Also posted a question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572805/cinnamon-hangs-immediately-after-startup-no-interaction-with-panel-and-popup-no) and [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/574378/fully-un-and-reinstall-cinnamon-all-config-data-and-stuff-too). No solutions yet, just a workaround (replacing the user). I'm interested whether your issue will attract more potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to follow the instructions given at:
[How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)
to reset Gnome 3 to its initial state.
It brought everything back in order (although I'm curious of which specific configuration was responsible).

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds like you've made some valiant attempts to correct the problem. Kudos.

Perhaps try the command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/settings-daemon/
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/
```

If those don't work, and you're desperate, you can try this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

And that will reset all GNOME application dconf keys to their defaults.

I can't guarantee that this will work, but it will reset GNOME settings to their defaults.

Comment: Please look again at your lines containing the commands. They seem not to fit to the descriptions you wrote. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot check if this would have indeed solved the problem since I have already solved it.